normalizeRAVEL: Could not find function ".write_brain"
I am using the normalizeRavel function of the RAVEL library.
I have the following R code:
library(pbapply)
library(neurobase)

source("./normalizeRAVEL.R")

dir = "/users/9/reine097/data/fairview-ag/anonymized/4_processed/"
input.files  <- list.files(dir, full.names=TRUE)
brain.mask <- "/users/9/reine097/mni_icbm152_t1_tal_nlin_sym_09a_mask_int16.nii.gz" 
# Confirm the input arguments match the expected format and data types for the normalizeRAVEL function.
control.mask <- "/users/9/reine097/data/fairview-ag/anonymized/6_control_mask/control_mask_08.nii.gz"
check_nifti(brain.mask)
check_nifti(control.mask)
tryCatch({
  normalizeRAVEL(input.files, brain.mask = brain.mask, control.mask = control.mask, k=1, writeToDisk=TRUE, WhiteStripe=FALSE)
}, error = function(e) {
  message("Error: ", e)
})

I am getting the following error:
Error: Error in .write_brain(brain.norm = V.norm[, i], output.file = output.files[i], : could not find function ".write_brain"

Does this means I am missing a Neuroconductor package? However, I have no idea which one is the correct one or if that is indeed the problem.
This is the shortest code needed to reproduce the problem.
Any ideas?

I am not familiar with any of the packages you are using. However, your reprex does not include a library(RAVEL) call yet you appear source one of the package files. That strikes me as very suspicious.

That's because I am using the code directly.  I cloned it from GitHub.

We dunno how you cloned that package. Just install it if possible: https://github.com/Jfortin1/RAVEL?tab=readme-ov-file#installation I can see that .write_brain is included in the package: https://github.com/Jfortin1/RAVEL/blob/410ae1ed831a84315bfca70f790441de07f7eafc/R/utils.R#L81
